# JQuery form validation - validate form based on other form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I"m using Jquery form validation which in the basic form looks like this

```
$('#shopping_form').validate({          
  submitHandler: function(){
  $.post("/url", { message: messageval}, function(data) {
  ......
  ......
  },
}
,rules: {
    message: { required:true },
    price: { number: true  }                
}
});
```

Now I am adding two radio buttons to this form call them radio1 and radio2.
If radio1 is selected then the field message is required and for radio2 its not a required field.

How can I add this kind of rule.
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a custom method which checks radio button value and depending on that value , it checks for message field. Here is the code you can add in jQuery

```
$.Validation.addRule("message",{
 check: function(value) {
    // Check the value of radio button here, You can do it as 
      if($("form input:radio:checked").val() == 'radio2') return true;
     // radio2 is checked then return valid, ie. this field is not required field.
    if(value.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
},
msg : "Field is required."
});
```